# Data migration tool - Migrate only categorys and products

Tags: category-products, magento2-migration-tool, magento-2.1.3

i have setup a fresh Magento 2.1.3 installation and i made all the required settings in the admin panel (incl. a new store and storeview).
Now i want to transfer the categories and the product data from the old Magento 1.9 installation. **Nothing else, only this data.**

Is there a way to configure the data migration tool in this way?
Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

In fact, migrate data (especially the "Map Step" where categories and products are transferred) always totally messed up my M2 installation.
After that always a bunch of errors occured.

Finally i managed it this way (maybe interesting for somebody else):

- Clean installation Magento 2 + migration tool
- DB backup
- Migrate settings
- Migrate data (complete; all steps)
- Export products in CSV
- Restore DB backup
- Migrate settings (with -r argument)
- Fix all errors in CSV file
- Import products
- Done

Now there is a proper Magento 2 base without any old filthy data and with all categories and products, voi­la...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the "steps" inside the config.xml already ?
There are various steps you can simply comment-out and/or delete.

Comment: OK, as i understand i have to run "bin/magento migrate:data" only. OK, but wich steps under <steps mode="data"> are required to migrate the categories and products? There are some steps i'm not sure about: "Data Integrity Step", "EAV Step", "Map Step", "Ratings Step", "ConfigurablePrices step", "Tier Price Step", "SalesIncrement Step", "PostProcessing Step". Could you please explain which steps i must keep at minimum?